# Why is it my Qshortcut consuming the Esc button press action?

Tags: c++, qt

So I have my application and it has two tests, the first test works as expected. When I pres Escape, it recognizes and when I press Escape 3x. It closes the application.

```
LFirstTest::LFirstTest(QWidget *parent,
                                             QObject *event_filter,
                                             SystemEvent *event, int dpi)
    : FirstTest(parent, event_filter, event) {
  (void)dpi;
  advanced_close_shortcut_ = make_unique<QShortcut>(
      QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Escape, Qt::Key_Escape, Qt::Key_Escape), this);
  advanced_close_shortcut_->setContext(Qt::WindowShortcut);
  connect(advanced_close_shortcut_.get(), &QShortcut::activated, this,
          &LFirstTest::OnClose);
```

But on the second application, it closes if I press Escape 3x, but it does not recognize the press of the Escape key once. It seems like it is consuming the action.

```
LSecondTest::LSecondTest(QWidget *parent,
                                           QObject *event_filter,
                                           SystemEvent *system_event, int dpi)
    : SecondTest(parent, event_filter, system_event) {
  (void)dpi;
  PopulateSecondStruct();
  keyboard_filter_ = new KeyboardFilter(this);
  ui->lineEdit->installEventFilter(keyboard_filter_);
  UpdateCheckBoxes();

  Second_close_shortcut_ = make_unique<QShortcut>(
      QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Escape, Qt::Key_Escape, Qt::Key_Escape), this);
  Second_close_shortcut_->setContext(Qt::WindowShortcut);
  connect(Second_close_shortcut_.get(), &QShortcut::activated, this,
          &LSecondTest::OnClose);

  DEBUG_FINISH;
}
```

Both codes are really similar, why is it one behaving different than the other?

Comment: Yes, `QShortcut` consumes the key press. Actually in Qt `QShortcuts` have priority over other key event processing, which is IMHO a bad design decision. If you want to give priority to the key press event instead of `QShortcut`, you have to "override" the shortcut with `QEvent::ShortcutOverride`. Search for shortcut override here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qevent.html However in your case it may be difficult and subsequently three presses of Escape will not be recognized. I do not think there is an easy solution of the conflicting shortcts in your case. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager, thanks! Is there any other way I can make my application call a function to close by pressing Escape 3x?
Why doesn't it happen on the first application?

Comment: What should your `KeyboardFilter` actually do with regards to Escape presses?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager , it allows my code to see what I pressed,

Comment: You should try to capture not only `QEvent::KeyPress` but also `QEvent::Shortcut` and `QEvent::ShortcutOverride` in the `KeyboardFilter`. Just experiment with it a bit, you will certainly find the answer.